# How to adjust sizes of x-axis in dendrogram (R)?

Tags: r, dendrogram, axis-labels

I would like to adjust the x-axis in a dendrogram where all the labels are seen, for large data sets. As example, I use iris data here:

```
    > iris.data=subset(iris,select=-Species)

    > d <- dist(iris.data, method="euclidean")

    > hc <- hclust(d, "ward")

    > plot(hc, hang=-1, main="Dendrogram of Ward's Method", label=iris$Species)
```

After the plot function is used, the dendrogram will be like this:

[image]

So, how I'm going to adjust the x-axis so then all the species are all clear seen.

Comment: I usually export dendrograms to a vector file with huge (in your case) width proportion. That way, the x axis gets stretched and enables the inspection of the labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Roman Luštrik said :
You can do like this :

```
  png("plotdendogram.png",width=1600,height=800)

  par(cex=1,font=3)
  plot(hc, hang=-1, main="Dendrogram of Ward's Method", label=iris$Species)

  dev.off()
```

You will be able to view species' names, although in small font size.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you@Sonal. After I try, we can also try this:Before the plot command run the line,        > par(cex=0.4)

Comment: Ya definitely. par function used here will set the graphics for the plot.you can read more about it in the R help file.You can use any of the par arguments whichever suits your problem the best.